# Moving pion actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm making a board game in actionscript I  have already made the script for dices.
Here is how it works.
When you click the button two random number between 1 and 6 will be show on your screen.
But I don't know how to make the script for the pion how can I make it move with the same number of the dices.
Here is my script of the dices

```
    btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, throw);
    function throw(event:MouseEvent):void {
// math random for dices 1 -- 6
dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
// Dice1 + Dice2
diceT = dice1 + dice2;
dice1_txt.text = dice1.toString();
dice2_txt.text = dice2.toString();
diceT_txt.text = "You have thrown " + diceT ;
    }
```

Comment: Well it's something that cannot be explained just like that. There are numerous options and ways to do it, so just start trying somehow..

Answer (score 0):

Prepare six images for numbers 1 to 6. Use sprite to draw pion as 1st child and number as 2nd child.